# How can I override ansible_become_user set in a host file with become_user at the task level?

Tags: git, ansible

I set `ansible_become` in my hosts file because I do most things as root when setting up a new machine.

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    ganymede:
      ansible_host: ganymede.xcv.org

  vars:
    ansible_user: ubuntu
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_user: root
```

I require the git repo to be cloned as the service account and I cannot figure out how to make that happen

```yaml
- name: Git
  vars:
    ansible_become: no
  block:
    - name: whoami
      command: whoami
      register: a
    - debug:
      msg: {{ a.stdout }}
    - git:
        repo: "git@github.com:fakerepo/ganymede.git"
        dest: "/opt/"
        force: yes
        key_file: ~ganymede/.ssh/id_ed25519
  become: yes
  become_user: ganymede
```

Unsetting `ansible_become` appears to work because the user is `ubuntu`.

Setting `become` and `become_user` has no effect and I want to know what it takes for that to work so that git works correctly.

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [ganymede] => {
    "msg": "ubuntu"
}
```

```
TASK [git] *************************************************
fatal: [ganymede]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote git@github.com:fakerepo/ganymede.git -h refs/heads/HEAD", 
    "msg": 
        "Warning: Identity file /home/ganymede/.ssh/id_ed25519 not accessible: Permission denied."
        "Host key verification failed."
        "fatal: Could not read from remote repository."
        "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.",
    "rc": 128, 
    "stderr": 
        "Warning: Identity file /home/ganymede/.ssh/id_ed25519 not accessible: Permission denied."
        "Host key verification failed."
        "fatal: Could not read from remote repository."
        "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Warning: Identity file /home/ganymede/.ssh/id_ed25519 not accessible: Permission denied.", 
        "Host key verification failed.", 
        "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.", 
        "", 
        "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."
    ], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [sivel](https://github.com/sivel), one of the member of Ansible development team:

> This behavior is documented under precedence rules:
> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#precedence-categories
>
> Task/play keywords have lower precedence to variables, since they are
> less specific to a host.
>
> As such, the inventory variables, have higher precedence than your
> task specified `become_user`. The workaround for your configuration as
> you have found, is overriding `ansible_become_user` via `vars:` on the
> individual task.
>
> See also:
> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence

<sup>*Source: [Ansible issue 74929](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/74929#issuecomment-856198344)*</sup>

And so, from the documentation page cited in the issue:

> Ansible offers four sources for controlling its behavior. In order of precedence from lowest (most easily overridden) to highest (overrides all others), the categories are:
>
> - Configuration settings
> - Command-line options
> - Playbook keywords
> - Variables
>
> Each category overrides any information from all lower-precedence categories. For example, a playbook keyword will override any configuration setting.

<sup>*Source: [Controlling how Ansible behaves: precedence rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#precedence-categories)*</sup>

So, your fix is, as described, to override the *ansible_become_user* in the *vars:* section of that task:

```yaml
- git:
    repo: "git@github.com:fakerepo/ganymede.git"
    dest: "/opt/"
    force: yes
    key_file: ~ganymede/.ssh/id_ed25519
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: ganymede
```

---

And in order to resolve your further [`acl` issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/74830#issuecomment-848817825), you have to install the right `acl` Python package on you managed nodes, which can be achieved with this task (run as `root`):

```yaml
- pip:
    name: acl
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. I get this now: `Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chmod: invalid mode: ‘A+user:ganymede:rx:allow’`. I am able to do the git on the machine manually in the same directory, etc. so I know that the account has the required permissions in the dest directory. Thoughts?

Comment: I get the same error if I try a simpler `command: whoami\nvars:\n:ansible_become_user: ganymede` too.

Comment: You have an `acl` issue now: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/74830#issuecomment-848817825